# Progressive Web App: Passes light house test but won't promp user to add to home screen

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

Hey I am trying to set up Progressive Web App services on my application so that users will automatically be prompted to download the website to the hompage. As you can see it says that my service workers are set up to prompt the user but when I navigate to the site from a iphone or android it does not prompt me to download the page to the homescreen.

[image: Lighthouse Test]

src/content/js/app/**App.js**:

```
_registerServiceWorker() {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register("../../content/js/app/service-worker.js", { scope: "/" }).then(function (registration) {
                console.log('Service worker registration succeeded:', registration);
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log('Service worker registration failed:', error);
            });;
        });
    }
}
```

src/content/js/app/**Service-Worker.js**:

```
/*
 *  In order for Service-Worker.js and Cache Api to work Javascript 
     Debugging must be disabled! 
 */

 /* Called when the app is being registered */
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
    let timeStamp = Date.now();
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.open("Intra").then(cache => {
            if (cache != undefined) {
                return cache.addAll([
                    "/"
                ]);
                cache.delete('/__webpack_hmr');
            }
            else {
                throw ("src/content/js/app/service-worker.js: you must disable javascript debugging in Debug/Options, service workers do not work with visual studio debugger.");
            }
        }).then(() => self.skipWaiting())
    );
});

/* Called after the app has been registered */
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

/* Fetch API */
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {

    //Ignore unauthorized requests
    if (event.request.cache === 'only-if-cached' && event.request.mode !== 'same-origin') return;

    //Possible Problem
    if (event.request.url.includes('__webpack_hmr')) return;

    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(response => {
            return response || fetch(event.request).catch(error => {
                console.log(error, event);
            });;
        })
    );
});

/*addEventListener('message', messageEvent => {
    if (messageEvent.data === 'skipWaiting') return skipWaiting();
});*/
```

src/Views/shared/**_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<link rel="manifest" href="@Url.Content("~/content/pwa/manifest.json")" />
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="application-name" content="Intra">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Intra">
<link rel="icon" sizes="144x144" href="../../content/pwa/icons/favicon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../../content/pwa/icons/favicon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="msapplication-TileImage" href="../../content/pwa/icons/favicon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="msapplication-TileColor" href="#fff" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#fff">
<meta name="og:title" content="Intra">
<meta name="og:type" content="website">
<meta name="og:image" content="../../content/pwa/favicon-144x144.png">
<meta name="og:url" content="/">
<meta name="og:description" content=" ">

<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
@Html.RenderCssBundle("app-stripped.css", BundleOptions.BuildConfigDependent)
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@current.GetCustomUIUrl()" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@current.GetHomeDesignerThemesUrl()" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

@if (!Html.IsDebug())
{
    @Instrumentation.InstrumentationScript()
}
```

**Web.Config**:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
    <remove name="X-XSS-Protection" />
    <remove name="X-Content-Type-Options" />
    <remove name="Strict-Transport-Security" />
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
    <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" />
    <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=8; IE=9; IE=EDGE" />
    <add name="Service-Worker-Allowed" value="/" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="/" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**Console**: 
[image]

I have been banging my head on this the past couple of days

Comment: Did you try to clear your browser data? Because the prompt only pops up on the second visit and never again

Comment: yes, very many times.

Comment: Do you get the correct homescreen app, when you add to homescreen manually?

Comment: yes. I do. Fetch results will fail on localhost:3000/__webpack_hmr though

Comment: I don't even know if that's relevant though.

Comment: So it could be that it works fine, but your browser already locked it. The only other thing to test would be on another phone or browser

Comment: I have tried from multiple and get the same result. I don't know what's happening with those fetch events though.

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel do you mean a device that has never been to the website even before PWA's were implemented?

Comment: Im also running on localhost and access through my computers IP

Comment: Would be good, just to be sure

Comment: Yeah that's not the problem I just ran from a fresh android device with no luck on the second refresh.

Comment: I updated my code.... idk if the fetch for the webpack hmr is important but it was throwing an error in the console so I caught it with an if statement and returned... Now there are no error messages in my console but there is still no pop up banner on any device I try to connect by ip to my PC's local host

Answer (score 1):

Based on lighthouse result, only possibility is first alert is missed/dismissed by the user/you or it came for a very brief period and gone on cases like reload.

If you test your URL in a new android phone which you have never used to load your page and if the site still doesn't prompt, it should be the below 4th criteria not met.

"Meets a site engagement heuristic defined by Chrome (this is regularly being changed)."

[Here](https://infrequently.org/2016/09/what-exactly-makes-something-a-progressive-web-app/) and [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/) are some official criteria info from Google on install banners.

Comment: Yeah well when the site user goes to the root site they are redirected to their companies extensions i.e. www.site.com redirects to www.site.com/company does it load for every page?

Comment: It would be nice to make the start url in the manifest dynamic and dependent on the global variable for the companies name.

Comment: @MichaelCollins I don't get what kind of global variable you are referring to and how you want to use that for making the URL dynamic. To my knowledge, we cannot make anything in manifest.json as its a plain meta file, unlike Service worker file which is JS and there you can get params form server to configure things like push notifications.

Comment: @MichaelCollins If you simply wants to decide your home page URL itself dynamic, you can have a routing service as your home page and that decides the actual home page. Caching becomes tricky with that.